# how to add post reactions telegram bot node.js

Tags: node.js, bots, telegram-bot

Can you help me? 
I don't know how to add reactions as like\dislike to any message in my telegram bot with written by Node.JS

The problem is I don't know how to change query.message.message_id because message_id every time is different on other chats.

How to count like\dislike I don't know yet too.

Can someone explain to me how to do it well?

Thanks

```
bot.on('callback_query', query => {
const chatID = query.message.chat.id

switch (query.data) {
    case 'good':
        console.log(query)

        User.find({}).then(users => {
            for(var i=0; i < users.length; i++){
                var pars = users[i]
                bot.editMessageReplyMarkup({
                    inline_keyboard: [
                        [
                            {
                                text: '1',
                                callback_data: 'good'
                            },
                            {
                                text: '',
                                callback_data: 'bad'
                            }
                        ]
                    ]
                }, {chat_id: pars.telegramId, message_id: query.message.message_id}).catch(e => console.log(e))
            }
        })

        break
    case 'bad':

        break
}
```

})

Answer (score 0):

Here for you:

```
const helpKeyboard = [[{
  text: `back`,
  callback_data: `back3`
}]]



bot.on('callback_query', msg => {
  if (msg.data == `back3`) {
    bot.editMessageText(`?`, {
      parse_mode: 'Markdown',
      message_id: msg.message.message_id,
      chat_id: msg.message.chat.id,
      reply_markup: {
        inline_keyboard: [[{
          text: ``,
          callback_data: `?`
        }]]
      }
    })
  }
}
```